# How to handle the deletion of my registraion_id in my online database server if the gcm enabled android app is uninstalled without internet connection

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Thinking of a problem that I already have 20 app instances of the app installed on different devices and I have decided that I want to install another one of this app on my newly bought device. This would really be a big problem in terms of obtaining a notification key right? because the max registration id that is allowed for notificatin_key members is 20, so I should limit my app instances.

One of the solution is to uninstall a single app instance from a device and tell my online database server to delete the saved registration id similar to the registration id of the uninstalled app. In this way, I have a permission to install the app on my newly bought device by checking my registration id field in my database if its less than or not equal to maximum number registration id which 20. Let's assume that I don't have an internet connection when I am uninstalling the app on the device. How can I update my online database server and provide another space for the newly bought device.

For those who are experienced developer of this kind of android app. Please share your thoughts on how can I properly handle this kind of situations. thanks!

Comment: i don't think there is such a limit from where do you get that? Have you read that in official link please post the source

Comment: Yes there is, kindly go to the link and see message parameter table http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server.html or you could go to this link https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/notifications.html @PramodYadav

Comment: I mean in terms of obtaining notification_key there is a limit of its registration_id members which is 20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read [**Interpreting an error response**](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html#error_codes) in details. Your server will get *Unregistered Device* error [error code is `NotRegistered`] if application has been uninstalled from device.

So if you get this error, you can remove entry for that particular device from server's database.

---

From [documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html#error_codes)

### Unregistered Device

An existing registration ID may cease to be valid in a number of scenarios, including:

- If the application manually unregisters by issuing a `com.google.android.c2dm.intent.UNREGISTER` intent.
- *`If the application is automatically unregistered, which can happen (but is not guaranteed) if the user uninstalls the application.`*
- If the registration ID expires. Google might decide to refresh registration IDs.
- If the application is updated but the new version does not have a broadcast receiver configured to receive `com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE` intents.

For all these cases, you should remove this registration ID from the 3rd-party server and stop using it to send messages. 
Happens when error code is `NotRegistered`.

Comment: Thanks for your good answer! but what if all of my registration id are all valid but the notification key only allowed 20 members for its registraion id. do you think limiting the app instances to maximum of 20 is still a good idea? @Pankaj Kumar

Comment: @KirbyAbadilla No. I read that line from documentation, but I have doubt about if there is any limitation (it may be that line is for example code only). First do one thing, try with more than 20 ids at same time. If you get error about that limit, you can use loop into sever code to use 20 ids on a time if ids are more than 20.